# Override AWS SDK API Call

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I want to implement caching mechanism for AWS SDK calls like describeReservations() in EC2 and so on.
I can create a wrapper around SDK and create custom SDK but that's a long process. So, I was looking for something like overriding API calls in AWS SDK itself and using some custom function to do so.
How can I modify AWS SDK code for java available on github in such a way to implement this mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this can help 
ResponseMetadataCache

```
public ResponseMetadataCache(int maxEntries)
```

Creates a new cache that will contain, at most the specified number of entries.

Parameters:

maxEntries - The maximum size of this cache.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/ResponseMetadataCache.html#ResponseMetadataCache-int-

Comment: I want to intercent the HTTP requests and implement caching of my own using redis or whatever. They use their internal cache and also this is for diagnostic purpose